# Exporting dataTable data as CSV doesn't show any data in the downloaded file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv, datatable

How can I export data in CSV or PDF format in a dataTable using an HTML button click instead of the DataTable generated button?

I tried exporting data using `$("#export").click(function(){ $("table").tableToCSV(); });` method.

But no data is shown in the downloaded csv file.

How to add export functionality to the HTML button?

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/helloIndia/2nary46x/5/

HTML:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-content mt-5" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="kt_tab_pane_all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="kt_tab_pane_all">
    <div class="Inner_kt_tableR">
      <div class="Inner_kt_tableR_top">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="Inner_kt_tableR_top_inner">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addstaffModal" class="form_brntnxd minwdth mrbtmklright">Add</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="form_brntnxd minwdth archiv mrbtmklright borbtn">Archive</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="form_brntnxd minwdth archiv mrbtmklright borbtn">Export</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="form_brntnxd minwdth borbtn mrbtmklright">Import</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="form_brntnxd minwdth borbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addfilterfModal">Filters • 3</a>
              <div class="f_p_searchk"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="cool_page_nitionsd_main">
              <div class="cool_page_info" id="student_page_info"></div>
              <div class="cool_page_nitionsd" id="student_page_nitionsd"></div>
              <div class="cool_page_viewd" id="student_page_viewd"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dt_kdtable forcheckqbox">
        <!--begin: Datatable-->
        <button>
        EXPORT AS CSV
        </button>
        <table id="allstudent_dt" class="table display table-checkable setclose" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="dt-left" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 30px;">
                <label class="checkbox checkbox-single">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="group-checkable">
                  <span></span>
                </label>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Exp.</th>
              <th>Level</th>
              <th>Date Added</th>
              <th>Last Contact</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
        <!--end: Datatable-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Js:

```
var jsonData = [
    {
       "id": "1",
       "name": "John Doe",
       "status": "Active",
       "grandex": "12/01/2020",
       "fundlevel": "100%",
       "dateadded": "Oct 27, 2020",
       "lastcontact": "Dec 31, 2020",
       "info": {
           "amount_paid": "$ 1,500.00",
           "credits_paid": "21 / 109",
           "expiration": "June 2024",
           "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
           "phone_number": "(321) 456-7890",
           "college": "Community College",
       }
    },
    {
       "id": "2",
       "name": "William Santiago",
       "status": "Active",
       "grandex": "12/01/2020",
       "fundlevel": "100%",
       "dateadded": "Oct 27, 2020",
       "lastcontact": "Dec 31, 2020",
       "info": {
           "amount_paid": "$ 1,500.00",
           "credits_paid": "21 / 109",
           "expiration": "June 2024",
           "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
           "phone_number": "(321) 456-7890",
           "college": "Community College",
       }
    }
];

var table = $('#allstudent_dt').DataTable({
  "dom": 'Btplis',
    buttons: [
            'csv'
    ],
  "language": {
    "responsive": true,
    "lengthMenu": "View _MENU_",
    "info": "_END_ of _TOTAL_",
    "paginate": {
      "next": "Next",
      "previous": "Prev"
    }
  },
  "data": jsonData,
  "initComplete": function() {
    $("#student_page_nitionsd").append($("#allstudent_dt_wrapper .dataTables_paginate"));
    $("#student_page_viewd").append($("#allstudent_dt_wrapper .dataTables_length"));
    $("#student_page_info").append($("#allstudent_dt_wrapper .dataTables_info"));
  },
  "columns": [
     { 
        "data": "id",
        "orderable": false,
        "render": function() {
           var html = '<label class="checkbox checkbox-single">' +
                  '<input type="checkbox" value="" class="group-checkable">' +
                  '<span></span></label>';
                  
           return html;
        }
     },
     {
        "className": 'details-control',
        "orderable": false,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": ''
     },
     { "data": "name" },
     { "data": "status" },
     { "data": "grandex" },
     { "data": "fundlevel" },
     { "data": "dateadded" },
     { "data": "lastcontact" }
  ],
  "order": [
    [2, 'asc']
  ],
});

function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Amount Paid:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.amount_paid + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Credits Paid:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.credits_paid + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Expiration:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.expiration + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Email:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.email + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Phone Number:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.phone_number + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr class="set_format_clool">'+
            '<td>Colleger:</td>'+
            '<td>' + d.info.college + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#allstudent_dt tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var row = table.row( tr );

   if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
  }
  else {
     // Open this row
     row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
     tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

Comment: If you google `jquery export html table to csv` then there is lots of guides

Comment: I tried exporting TableData using this method: - https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-HTML-Table-To-CSV-tabletoCSV.html

But the exported CSV doesn't show any data in that. I have updated the Fiddle also.
Please check @CarstenLøvboAndersen